# Sectioning date header in a ListView that has adapter extended by CursorAdapter

Tags: android, android-listview, cursor, android-cursoradapter

I am trying to build a demo chatting App.I want to show the messages with section headers as Dates like "Today","Yesterday","May 21 2015" etc.I have managed to achieve this but since the new View method gets called whenever I scroll the list.The headers and messages get mixed up.

For simplicity, I have kept the header in the layouts itself and changing its visibility(gone and visible) if the date changes.

Can you help me out with this? Let me know if anyone needs any more info to be posted in the question.

```
public class ChatssAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private Cursor mCursor;
    private String mMyName, mMyColor, mMyImage, mMyPhone;
    // private List<Contact> mContactsList;
    private FragmentActivity mActivity;
    private boolean mIsGroupChat;

    public ChatssAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, boolean groupChat) {
        super(context, c, false);
        mContext = context;
        mMyColor = Constants.getMyColor(context);
        mMyName = Constants.getMyName(context);
        mMyImage = Constants.getMyImageUrl(context);
        mMyPhone = Constants.getMyPhone(context);
        mIsGroupChat = groupChat;
        mCursor = c;
        // mActivity = fragmentActivity;
        /*try {
            mContactsList = PinchDb.getHelper(mContext).getContactDao().queryForAll();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }*/
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        Cursor cursor = (Cursor) getItem(position);
        return getItemViewType(cursor);
    }


    private int getItemViewType(Cursor cursor) {
        boolean type;

        if (mIsGroupChat)
            type = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Chat.COLMN_CHAT_USER)).compareTo(mMyPhone) == 0;
        else type = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Chat.COLMN_FROM_ME)) > 0;
        if (type) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = null;
        int itemViewType = getItemViewType(cursor);
        if (v == null) {
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            if (itemViewType == 0) {
                v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_chat_outgoing, parent, false);
            } else {
                v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_chat_incoming, parent, false);
            }
        }
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
        View v = view;
        final Chat chat = new Chat(cursor);
        boolean fromMe = mIsGroupChat ? chat.getUser().compareTo(mMyPhone) == 0 : chat.isFrom_me();

        if (fromMe) {

            // LOGGED IN USER'S DATA SETTING....
            holder.chat_name = (StyleableTextView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.chat_user_name);

            holder.chat_time = (StyleableTextView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.chat_time);

            holder.chat_tag = (StyleableTextView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.chat_tag);

            int color = Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF");
            v.setBackgroundColor(color);

            holder.chat_name.setText("#You");
            holder.chat_time.setText(AppUtil.getEventTime(chat.getTimestampLong()));

            // header text setting and process..
            holder.chat_header_text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.header_text);


            String str_date = AppUtil.covertToDate(chat.getTimestampLong());
            String pref_date = SharePreferencesUtil.getSharedPreferencesString(mContext, Constants.CHAT_TIMESTAMP, "");

            if (!str_date.equalsIgnoreCase(pref_date)) {
                holder.chat_header_text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                SharePreferencesUtil.putSharedPreferencesString(mContext, Constants.CHAT_TIMESTAMP, str_date);
                holder.chat_header_text.setText(str_date);
            } else {
                holder.chat_header_text.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }



            String firstWord, theRest;
            String mystring = chat.getText();
            String arr[] = mystring.split(" ", 2);

            if (arr.length > 1) {
                firstWord = arr[0]; // the word with hash..
                theRest = arr[1];   // rest of the body..

                holder.chat_tag.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#999999\"><b>" + firstWord + "</b></font>" + "  " + "<font color=\"#000000\">" + theRest + "</font>"));
                // holder.chat_text.setText(theRest);
                // holder.chat_text.setClickable(false);
            } else {
                String msg = arr[0]; // the word with hash..
                holder.chat_tag.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#999999\"><b>" + msg + "</b></font>"));
                //holder.chat_text.setText("");
            }

            updateTimeTextColorAsPerStatus(holder.chat_time, chat.getStatus());
            v.setTag(holder);

        } else {

            // OTHER USER'S DATA SETTING....

            holder.chat_name = (StyleableTextView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.chat_user_name);

            holder.chat_time = (StyleableTextView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.chat_time);


            holder.chat_tag = (StyleableTextView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.chat_tag);


            holder.chat_image = (ImageView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.chat_profile_image);

            String image = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("image"));
            String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
            String color = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("color"));

            // set the values...
            if (holder.chat_image != null) {
                MImageLoader.displayImage(context, image, holder.chat_image, R.drawable.round_user_place_holder);
            }

            int back_color = Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF");
            v.setBackgroundColor(back_color);

            holder.chat_name.setText(name);
            holder.chat_time.setText(AppUtil.getEventTime(chat.getTimestampLong()));

            // header text setting and process..
            holder.chat_header_text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.header_text);

            String str_date = AppUtil.covertToDate(chat.getTimestampLong());
            String pref_date = SharePreferencesUtil.getSharedPreferencesString(mContext, Constants.CHAT_TIMESTAMP, "");
            Log.d("eywa", "str date is ::::: " + str_date + "  pref date is :::::: " + pref_date);
            /*if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(pref_date)) {
                if (!pref_date.contains(str_date)) {
                    holder.chat_header_text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    SharePreferencesUtil.putSharedPreferencesString(mContext, Constants.CHAT_TIMESTAMP, pref_date + str_date);
                    holder.chat_header_text.setText(str_date);
                } else {
                    holder.chat_header_text.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            } else {
                holder.chat_header_text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                SharePreferencesUtil.putSharedPreferencesString(mContext, Constants.CHAT_TIMESTAMP, pref_date + str_date);
                holder.chat_header_text.setText(str_date);

            }*/
            if (!str_date.equalsIgnoreCase(pref_date)) {
                holder.chat_header_text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                SharePreferencesUtil.putSharedPreferencesString(mContext, Constants.CHAT_TIMESTAMP, str_date);
                holder.chat_header_text.setText(str_date);
            } else {
                holder.chat_header_text.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }


            String firstWord, theRest;
            String mystring = chat.getText();

            String arr[] = mystring.split(" ", 2);
            if (arr.length > 1) {
                firstWord = arr[0]; // the word with hash..
                theRest = arr[1];   // rest of the body..

                holder.chat_tag.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#999999\"><b>" + firstWord + "</b></font>" + "  " + "<font color=\"#000000\">" + theRest + "</font>"));
                // holder.chat_text.setClickable(false);
            } else {
                String msg = arr[0]; // the word with hash..
                holder.chat_tag.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#999999\"><b>" + msg + "</b></font>"));
                // holder.chat_text.setText("");
            }

            String phone = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("user"));
            final Contact contact = new Contact(name, phone, "", color, image);

            if (holder.chat_image != null) {
                holder.chat_image.setTag(contact);

//            holder.chat_name.setTag(contact);
                holder.chat_image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Contact con = (Contact) v.getTag();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, OtherProfileActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra(Constants.EXTRA_CONTACT, con);
                        mContext.startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
            }

            v.setTag(holder);
        }


        /*else
        {
            view=
        }*/
    }


    private void updateTimeTextColorAsPerStatus(TextView chat_time, int status) {
        if (status == 0) chat_time.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        else {
            chat_time.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
           /* if (status == 1)
                chat_time.setTextColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));*/
            if (status == 2)
                chat_time.setTextColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.darker_gray));
            else if (status == 3)
                chat_time.setTextColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black));
        }
    }


    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        public StyleableTextView chat_name;
        public StyleableTextView chat_time;
        public StyleableTextView chat_tag;
        public ImageView chat_image;
        public TextView chat_header_text;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        if (getCursor() == null) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return getCursor().getCount();
        }
    }
}
```